# Select a p tag depending on its content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML script

```
<p> some content </p>
<p> <img src="img.jpg"/>
<p> some text content </p>
```

Now, what I want to do is change the width of that paragraph which content image inside it, But rest of the paragraphs having text content will remain the same.

**Say in our case:**

Paragraph containing `text : width=80%`

Paragraph containing `image : width = 100%`

Can I achieve this through jQuery?

I tried some selectors `:has` and some others, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/onomcctx/?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:has` selector:

```
 $('p:has("img")').css('width','100%');
```

Comment: Ya, I achieved it with `:has` `jQuery('.post-content p:has(img)').addClass( "full-width-p" )`

Comment: but can we do this using inline css??

Comment: CSS do not have has selector. this can not be achieved with pure CSS.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar "this can not be achieved with pure CSS" ...yet. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the DOM using a `parents` function in jQuery.

```
$( 'p' ).css( 'width', '80%' );
$( 'img' ).parents( 'p' ).css( 'width', '100%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented rather easily in plain JavaScript: just process all `p` elements, checking whether the element contains any `img` elements, and if not, setting its width. So unless you have special reasons (like uniformity of coding) to use jQuery, you can do it as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if(p[i].getElementsByTagName('img').length == 0) {
      p[i].style.width = '80%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p { outline: solid red } /* Just to show the widths */
```

```html
<p> some content </p>
<p> <img src="img.jpg"/>
<p> some text content </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to select the image node inside the paragraph, and once you get that object, just ask for its parent node